# WebElements are not displayed properly on page in robot framework

Tags: python

I am working with robot framework on UI testing of web application. IN which I use chrome browser, and load application by writing robot script. but some web elements are not displayed properly on page for chrome, firefox and edge also. I try it on my team mates machine It working fine means web elements are displayed properly. This issue is occur only on my machine for chrome, firefox and edge.
I am not able to find out the cause.

Expectation is web elements are properly visible on page.

Comment: Had you checked your brower versions? local vs production

Comment: I use latest versions of browsers and drivers as well. What do you mean by local vs production?

Comment: check your and your team mate browser version, also chromedriver (for chrome) or geckodriver (firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will help to solve your problem:
1-check the stable version of chrome or edge driver
2-use the robot assertions to check either element is visible, you can use
"wait until element is visible "
"wait until page contains"
"page should contains"
3-try to make a copy of your project,clean your cache
4-copy all scripts and use with fresh copy of project
5-check the robot seleniumlibrary version